# How to find first previous occurrence of string resulting from grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to find a string occurring before my grep result.

```
before = text1234
foo = 1234
bar = 1234
var = words
    
before = text2345
foo = 2345
bar = 2345
etc = 2345
var = words
```

I am using grep `grep -n var *` to get the results of var. But I am trying to find the first occurrence of `before` before the grepped line.

I have tried using the `grep -B 10` option, but since the lines are variable it is not exactly what I want.

The ideal result would return:

```
   before = text1234
    before = text2345
```

I think there is some sed/awk magic that would help, but I am not sure what it could be based on my google-fu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `awk` is to match `before =` at the start of the string and then store the line.

Then when you encounter `var =` at the start of the string, check if there is a stored value for `before =`  and then print that value.

```
awk '
/^before =/ {b=$0; next}
/^var =/ && b {print b; b=""}
' file
```

Output

```
before = text1234
before = text2345
```

---

Another option using a field separator of  `=`  and checking the first field values:

```
awk -F" = " '
$0 == "" {b="";next}
$1 == "before" {b=$0; next}
$1 == "var" && b {print b; b=""}
' file
```

Comment: You should probably reset `b` when a blank line is encountered in case the input has a block with `before` but no subsequent `var` and then the next block has `var` with no preceding `before`.

Comment: ++ for the second awk that does it with more precision

Comment: @EdMorton That is a good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` one-liner should do the job:

```
sed -n '/^before =/h; /^var =/{x; p;}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` approach that works with shown example data:

```bash
awk '/^before /,/^var /{if ($1 == "before") print}' file

before = text1234
before = text2345
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining `grep` is easy here, too:

`grep -e before -e var file | grep -B1 var | grep -v var`

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the other answers using awk and grep:

```
awk '/var/' RS= file | grep before
```

The `awk` part "greps" in "records" that are separated by empty lines. The `grep` part "greps" for `before` in the records found by awk that contain `var`.

Note that this solution relies in the blocks you are searching to be separated by an empty line.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk and that would give a false match given various input values.

Comment: @Ed Morton: I disagree, its perfectly ok grep awks output if it saves me writing more verbose awk code when writing throwaway one liners. That seems like an artificial and pedantic rule.

Comment: @Ed Morton: I'm interested in how this will generate false matches (given the caveat I note). Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure. Try it if the input had `var = foo`  before `before = bar` in a block or a block contained `var = this before that` or ` var` or `before` existed in any other contexts in the input.

Comment: It continues to work if the `var` line is moved above the `before` line. The other issues can solved by `| grep ^before`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work - the OP said (emphasis mine) `I am trying to find a string occurring **before** my grep result.`, not that they wanted to find a value anywhere in the same input as their target string. No, that's not all it'd take to solve the other issues, you'd need to add `\n` before `var` too and add `<blank>=` after both `var` and `before` or, for example, `^before` would matched `beforested = foo` and `var` would still match anywhere in the input (e.g. `foovar = bar`, `before = various`)

Comment: Well if the input was structured differently then I would change my solution. You are asking for a different problem to be solved. eg `awk '/var/,/^$/' file | grep ^before`

Comment: It's not a different problem. All we know is the OP has some variable assignments in blocks and that those assignments can contain "text" and "words". It's not reasonable to assume that the variable names can't be part of other variable names, nor that they can't appear in the "text" or "words" in the right side of the assignments. `awk '/var/,/^$/' file | grep ^before` would not solve the problems I mentioned, nor would it produce the expected output from the posted sample input.

Comment: On reflection you are correct. I think I just approach questions like this differently, you seem to be looking for a correct and generalised solution whereas I am looking to produce the output requested by the OP given their input.

Comment: I do wish people would post questions with more than just the most trivial sunny-day cases for their sample input/output. It's always easy to match what you want matched but harder to not match similar text you do not want matched. If this question had blocks without `before` or `var` lines, cases of `foovar = stuff`, `var = this before that`, etc., i.e. some of the harder to handle cases, then it'd be much easier for us to help them without us having to guess at what those harder cases that will show up in the real world data might be.

Comment: Yes I agree, you say `All we know` and we probably do, but it requires reading between the lines. I should perhaps try not treat questions so much like shell golf challenges. I also notice my amended solution is entirely wrong as it explicitly omits the before context.